# BST size() that looks pretty

Tags: java, recursion, coding-style, binary-search-tree

I have two functions here for size() but they both look like crap. The first one uses an overloaded function and the second, well, see for yourself. What I want to do is create a slick version of the second attempt but I'm low on ideas.

P.S: Telling me to use Java's util is kind of pointless. I want to make it pretty, not hide it.

So my function is called from a BST object and looks like this:

```
 public int size() {
 return size(root);
 }

 private int size(Node x) {
 if (x == null) {
 return 0;
 } else {
 return 1 + size(x.left) + size(x.right);
 }
 }
```

Now I don't want to overload the function so I rewrote it as such:

```
public int size() {
    Node y = root;
    if (y == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        root = y.left;
        int left = size();
        root = y.right;
        int right = size();
        root = y;
        return 1 + left + right;
    }
}
```

All suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Your first approach looks far better than the 2nd one. What's wrong with overloading method?

Comment: Overloading is absolutely the right approach here.

Comment: Your 1st approach is perfect design decision

Comment: There's nothing wrong with overloading. IMO it's far worse to create that messy second function just to avoid something that isn't a problem.

Comment: Look at all the upvotes on comments telling you your first approach is better.  As a bonus you get a method that can give you the size of any subtree.  Your second approach is "rooted" at the root and cannot do that.  Your first approach is, IMHO, much "prettier".

Answer (score 1):

If it is something that is called regularly, perhaps you would be better caching the size in your `Node` class, and updating when you insert or delete, then it simply becomes

```
public int size() {
    return root == null ? 0 : root.size();
}
```

Comment: That's very pretty, I'll take it to heart.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO Your first approach is good enough. Why? Because you have a perfect public interface(`public size()`) that governs how the size of the BST is calculated(using `private size()`) hiding the internal implementation. I don't see any harm in overloading as long as it lead to a better design decision.

**Edit**: This is my understanding of how 1st one is better than the 2nd approach. I welcome any feedbacks. Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe you're right. I always felt overloading broke the idea of one function for one job. But yea, now you got me thinking ;)